# Call getter from other vuex module with parameter

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have `resident.js`

```
export default {
state : {
    residents: []
},
getters: {
    getResidentsById: (state) => (id) => {
        return state.residents.find(resident => resident.id === id)
    }
}
}
```

Now in another module :

```
actions: {
    get_registered_medication_list (context) {
        return medicationApi.getRegisteredMedication() 
            .then(medications => {
                const medicationArray = medications.map(medication => ({
                        ...medication,
                        residentName: context.rootGetters['resident/getResidentsById'](medication.resident)
                    })
                );
                context.commit('set_medication', medicationArray)
                return medicationArray
            })
            .catch(error => {
                return Promise.reject(error)
            })
    },
```

This is giving me **getResidentsById** is not a function. I wanted to set extrafield on medication list, i.e add residentName field, temporarly

Comment: Are you using `namespaced: true` when you register your `resident` module?

Comment: Share your store module.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your `resident` module object and set the property `namespaced` equals to true, so vuex will make it separated and accessible through `['myModule/myModuleResource']`

E.g.

```
const myModule = {
    namespaced: true,
    actions: {...},
    getters: {...},
    mutations: {...},
    state: {...},
}
export default myModule
```